# Ionic 3 Angular 5 app crashers on Android Opentok

Tags: ionic3, opentok

I have created an hybrid application using ionic 3 angular 5. This app uses opentok for video calling. I have installed a python server for opentok on my mac and it is working fine. No I am trying to connect to the same server via hybrid app. I have generated a session id form opentok website. I have also generated a publisher token form the same site and used it in the app. I am able to see both the stream, but as soon as the publisher from client is initialised app crashes.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var OT:any;
declare var Cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  session: any;
   publisher: any;
   apiKey: any;
   sessionId: string;
   token: string;

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.apiKey = '46271262';
        this.sessionId = '1_MX40NjI3MTI2Mn5- 
     MTU1MDU2MTE3NDk4OX5RcmQzSmQ2Z2VzZnl4RmNXNEY5ckJQc0V-fg';
    this.token = 
    'myTokenGoesHere';
    }

  startCall() {
    this.session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);

    this.session.on({
     streamCreated: (event) => {
    this.session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber');
    this.session.subscribe.subscribeToVideo = true
    OT.updateViews();
      },
     streamDestroyed: (event) => {
       console.log(`Stream ${event.stream.name} ended because 
  ${event.reason}`);
    OT.updateViews();        
    }
    });


     this.session.connect('myTokenGoeshere', () => {
      this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher');
      alert("Publish Started")

      this.session.publish(this.publisher);
     });
     }

    }
```

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please share the stacktrace when the crash happens? Is this for an iOS or Android application? For iOS, please make sure that you've added the permissions for the microphone and camera in the info.plist file. The Android plugin should be handling the permissions for you, but in case please make sure the permissions are granted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Its crashing on Android.

Comment: Hi Evangelist, I could solve the crash by generating a new token. I tried creating a native IOS app and got error with code1500. It was related to token. So I generated a new token used it in the android app and the crash got resolved.

Comment: Now I have another problem, when I created an IOS build from hybrid app, I could see the stream coming form python server to app, but could not see the stream going form IOS app to python server. I think again this could be related to token? I tried generating a fresh token, but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

It looks like you're publishing without verifying if the session was connected without an error. There was a recent bug fix in the [Cordova OpenTok Plugin](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok) that fixed the error handler issue for the `session.connect` method. You can modify your Ionic code to something like this:

```
this.session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher');
this.session.on({
  streamCreated: (event) => {
    this.session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber');
  },
  streamDestroyed: (event) => {
    console.log(`Stream ${event.stream.name} ended because ${event.reason}`);
  },
 sessionConnected: event => {
    this.session.publish(publisher);
  },
});

this.session.connect(this.token, (error) => {
   if (error) {
      console.log('There was an error connecting');
   }
});
```

I've also gone ahead and updated the samples in the [OpenTok-Ionic-Samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ionic-samples) and the [OpenTok-Cordova-Samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-cordova-samples) repos that reflect the sample code changes for the bug fix.